# Как получить данные из JSON?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить значение usd но ничего не выходит из-за того, что не могу использовать название первого значения в json ответе.

```
$json = '{"bitcoin":{"usd":56991}}';
$usd = $json['bitcoin']['usd'];
```

Как получить число 56991 не используя bitcoin?

Спасибо!

Comment: _Как получить число 56991 не используя bitcoin?_ зачем и почему так надо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо использовать json_decode: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = '{"bitcoin":{"usd":56991}}';
$usd = json_decode($json, true)['bitcoin']['usd'];
```

> Я не могу указать bitcoin при получении usd, как-то нужно его перескочить

Тогда так:

```
$json = '{"bitcoin":{"usd":56991}}';
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($json, true);
$innerData = array_pop($jsonDecoded);
$usd = $innerData['usd'];
echo $usd;
```

Comment: Я не могу указать bitcoin при получении usd, как-то нужно его перескочить.

Comment: Что значит не могу указать bitcoin?

Comment: Этот параметр динамический. Мой вариант $usd = $json['bitcoin']['usd']; работает, но в нем bitcoin динамический, если его прописать в код, то для других валют будет тоже bitcoin.

Comment: @Иван см. обновлённый ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно пропарсить строку JSON и только потом применять ее данные. Для этого используйте `json_decode`.
Например:

```
$json = '{"bitcoin":{"usd":56991}}';
$data = json_decode($json);

$bitcoin = $data->bitcoin;
$usd = $bitcoin->usd;
```

или

```
$json = '{"bitcoin":{"usd":56991}}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$bitcoin = $data['bitcoin'];
$usd = $bitcoin['usd'];
```

Подробнее о `json_decode` можете прочитать в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: В данной строке $usd = $data->{'bitcoin'}->{'usd'};
как-то можно обойтись без {'bitcoin'}?

Comment: Вы можете взять массив bitcoin в переменную и использовать ее: `$bitcoin = $data['bitcoin']; $usd = $bitcoin['usd'];`. Ну, или `$bitcoin = $data->{'bitcoin'}; $usd = $bitcoin->{'usd'};`, если это не массивы, а объекты.

Comment: Зачем вы суёте эти скобки со строками ужасные, где не надо?... `$data->bitcoin->usd` и выглядит лучше и понятней

Comment: скобки-строки в полях исполььзуются, когда имя поля содержит, например, пробел и его нельзя использовать напрямую при доступе к свойству объекта

Comment: Приношу извинения. Исправил

Comment: А ответ-то не отвечает на поставленный вопрос

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо, что заметили

Comment: Так он всё так же и не отвечает. Вопрос был "Как получить число 56991 **не используя bitcoin**"